# Remove child node results in empty parent node

Tags: xml, xslt

I am new to XSLT and I followed the article below to implement my requirement. My requirement is to remove the parent node completely if a condition in the child node is met. Same as the article below.

[deleting the parent node if child node is not present in xml using xslt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14779124/deleting-the-parent-node-if-child-node-is-not-present-in-xml-using-xslt)

In reference to the example in the above article, I was able to remove the content under `<car>`. However, my source xml has a twist. The twist is that it has a namespace.

For example:

source xml

```
<car xmlns="urn:test:v2xml">
 .....
</car>
```

output xml:

```
<car/>
```

In my implementation, the result was an empty car node in my XML output. I am expecting the car node to be completed removed but no matter what I tried, the empty car node remains in the output xml.

Is there a way to completely remove that car node? I suspect that my namespace has something to do with it because without the namespace, it works and the tag is completely removed.

Comment: You have illustrated the dangers of trying to learn a programming language by copying examples. It's not a good learning strategy. Find a book that explains the concepts of the language well enough so that you understand the examples before copying them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You'll need to specify the namespace for `car`, taking care of whether you want to squelch `car` or `Car`:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:v2="urn:test:v2xml"
                version="1.0">
    <!--Identity template to copy all content by default-->
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="v2:car[not(Price)]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Yes, I have this in my implementation. The same behavior occurs. Is it possible that the schema for this namespace dictates a minOccurrence of 1 and hence XSLt is forcing an empty car node?

Comment: @CharlieLee:  Please provide an [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that exhibits the problem.  I will not attempt to answer further until you do this.  Thanks.

Comment: fair enough. I appreciate your response tho.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve what I wanted by chaining a second transformation process to remove the empty node. It's called multi-pass. Thus, in a single XSLT stylesheet, the first output was created with the empty node. Then in a second transformation in the same stylesheet, a search is made to remove the empty nodes. The final output provided the cleaned result. Example of two-pass transformation is here:

[Two phase processing: Do not output empty tags from phase-1 XSLT 2.0 processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3199560/two-phase-processing-do-not-output-empty-tags-from-phase-1-xslt-2-0-processing)