# Remove parent node if child node is empty

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I am trying to transform a given XML using xslt. The caveat is that I would have to delete a parent node if a given child node is not present. I did do some template matching, but I am stuck. Any help would be appreciated.

The input xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<main>
     <item>
        <value>
           <item>
              <value>ABC</value>
              <key>test1</key>
           </item>
           <item>
              <value>XYZ</value>
              <key>test2</key>
           </item>
               <item>
              <value></value>
              <key>test3</key>
           </item>
        </value>
     </item>
     <item>
        <value />
        <key>test4</key>
     </item>
     <item>
        <value>PQR</value>
        <key>test5</key>
     </item>
</main>
```

Expected Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<main>
     <item>
        <value>
           <item>
              <value>ABC</value>
              <key>test1</key>
           </item>
           <item>
              <value>XYZ</value>
              <key>test2</key>
           </item>
        </value>
     </item>
     <item>
        <value>PQR</value>
        <key>test5</key>
     </item>
</main>
```

The issue is if I use template matching e.g.

`<xsl:template match="item[not(value)]"/>` as mentioned in [deleting the parent node if child node is not present in xml using xslt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14779124/deleting-the-parent-node-if-child-node-is-not-present-in-xml-using-xslt), then it completely removes everything as main/item/value is also empty.

What I need is remove  if  element is empty but only do if  element has no child element.

Comment: Additionally if value for key test1 and test2 is empty then top level item element should also be excluded from output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first start with the XSLT identity template

```
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
```

Then, all you need is a template that matches the `item` element where all descendent leaf `value` elements are empty.

```
 <xsl:template match="item[not(descendant::value[not(*)][normalize-space()])]" />
```

So, the template matches it, but doesn't output it.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="item[not(descendant::value[not(*)][normalize-space()])]" />

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This works like a charm. How does this xslt differentiate between main/item/value (which is empty and has child node item) against item/value? Is the not(*) doing the trick?

Comment: Yes. Doing `not(*)` checks for a lack of child elements, so it will only match the "leaf" elements.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to remove the element of it has no children at all (whether those children be elements or text nodes). Try inserting this template:

```html
<xsl:template match="item">
    <xsl:if test="exists(value/node())">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I tried it's not working and giving xslt compilation error. Error:XSLTProcessor::transformToXml(): xmlXPathCompiledEval: 1 objects left on the stack.

Comment: @Ady211 Are you sure you are using XSLT 2.0, as the tag on your question indicates?

Comment: I am using xslt 1.0.

Answer (score 0):

If I read this correctly, you want to do:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="item[not(value[node()])]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This will remove any `item` that does not have a `value` child with *some* content.